# Add custom files to a Visual Studio 2013 Multi Project Template

Tags: visual-studio-templates, multi-project

I am trying to create a Multi Project Template and that is working good. The projects are created. For this solution there are some 3:e party dll's that the projects shall add a reference to, and some other .txt and .xml files.

I have my .vstemplate like this:

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>AppFabric Services Solution Template</Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon></Icon>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.5</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="Domain">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Domain.Application">
          Domain\Application\Application.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink  ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Domain.Core">
          Domain\Core\Core.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

And want something like this

```
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="ProjectGroup" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
  <TemplateData>
    <Name>AppFabric Services Solution Template</Name>
    <Description></Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <Icon></Icon>
    <RequiredFrameworkVersion>4.5</RequiredFrameworkVersion>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <ProjectCollection>
      <SolutionFolder Name="_Library">
        <ProjectItem>THIRDPARTY.dll</ProjectItem>
      </SolutionFolder>
      <SolutionFolder Name="_SolutionItems">
        <ProjectItem>README.TXT</ProjectItem>
      </SolutionFolder>
      <SolutionFolder Name="Domain">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Domain.Application">
          Domain\Application\Application.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink  ProjectName="$safeprojectname$.Domain.Core">
          Domain\Core\Core.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
      </SolutionFolder>
    </ProjectCollection>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Is there anyway to do what I want?

Regards
/Magnus

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?  I am attempting to do the same